# How to set up scrapy project outside Scripts folder in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda

I'm pretty new to programming (~6 months) and everything I have donde before was through Anaconda/Spyder, so Scrapy was the first time I really had to use the console. It took me about 3 hours to figure out how to make the following command work:

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

The only way I managed to make it work was to open Anaconda prompt and set:

```
cd "C:\Users\jecon\Anaconda3\Scripts"
```

And so there I could finally open scrapy and start my project. But in most tutorials they start the project anywhere (usually a blank folder in the Desktop). Why is it that I can only summon Scrapy if I'm on its script folder but for most people it's not like that? Can I pre-load a script so I'm not forced to work on the script folder?

Sorry if I sound too beginner,

Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out! Didn't know about paths and setting them. But all I had to do was to set a path to the scripts folder and now I can run scrapy without having to be located exactly in the Scripts folder